# Create an object array with few object properties of another object array using map

Tags: swift

Suppose we have an **Employee** class like this

```
class Employee {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var role: String?
    var age: Int?
    var salary: Int?
}

var employeeList: [Employee]
```

I have to create a new object array with just few properties(eg: id, name, age) from `employeeList`.

Is there any other way(like map) other than using a for-loop to iterate the `employeeList`?

Comment: You could use `map` It is essentially a `for` loop anyway

Comment: You could map over multiple properties and create individual arrays. Or you could use forEach and iterate over everything and load it into any arrays you've created that way

Comment: Having all-optional fields is a really big code smell. What exactly would it mean to have an employee with a nil id, name, role, age and salary? that would be a strange coworker to have. "How old are you?" "nil."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to use `map`, you could do something like the following:

```
class Employee {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var role: String?
    var age: Int?
    var salary: Int?
}

var employeeList: [Employee]

var employeeModifiedList = employeeList.map {
    (id: $0.id, name: $0.name, age: $0.age)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
let myData: [(String?, String?, Int?)] = employeeList.map { ($0.id, $0.name, $0.age) }
```

Although not sure why your `id` is `String` type... usually ID's are `Int`